# Speech to text in multiple languages (support Persian and Arabic languages)

Tags: ios, api, speech

Does anyone know that in Convert Speech to text in multiple languages API in iOS support Persian and Arabic languages?
I use Swift language

Comment: Can You please explain in details ?

Comment: My program is such that the user chooses the language of choice, one of which is Farsi and the other is Arabic. After selecting the language, he will click on the button and speak as a result of his conversations in a box.I want to know if Ios has a code for Persian and Arabic languages ​​and covers them in my program.I used the Speech library to do this But there was no code for Persian and Arabic

Comment: You mean a speech recognizer?

Comment: Yes, and I want to add Farsi and Arabic to the program

Comment: According to `SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales()` it only support ar-SA.

Comment: Hi, what did you do for this question when it does't support Farsi ? google service supports but you should charge your google account ... 
Do you use any free service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that speech recognition is available for a certain locale using the [`isAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/1649885-isavailable) property :

```
let recognier = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "fa_IR"))

print(recognier?.isAvailable)   //nil
```

Sadly it's not available for Farsi.

But it is available for Arabic and most of its variants :

```
let recognier = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "ar_SA"))

print(recognier?.isAvailable)  //Optional(true)
```

---

To get all the supported locales use the type method [`supportedLocales()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/1649889-supportedlocales) :

```
print(SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales().sorted {
    $0.description < $1.description
})
```

Which outputs :

```
[ar-SA (fixed), ca-ES (fixed), cs-CZ (fixed), da-DK (fixed), de-AT (fixed), 
de-CH (fixed), de-DE (fixed), el-GR (fixed), en-AE (fixed), en-AU (fixed), 
en-CA (fixed), en-GB (fixed), en-ID (fixed), en-IE (fixed), en-IN (fixed), 
en-NZ (fixed), en-PH (fixed), en-SA (fixed), en-SG (fixed), en-US (fixed), 
en-ZA (fixed), es-419 (fixed), es-CL (fixed), es-CO (fixed), es-ES (fixed), 
es-MX (fixed), es-US (fixed), fi-FI (fixed), fr-BE (fixed), fr-CA (fixed), 
fr-CH (fixed), fr-FR (fixed), he-IL (fixed), hi-IN (fixed), hi-IN-translit (fixed), 
hi-Latn (fixed), hr-HR (fixed), hu-HU (fixed), id-ID (fixed), it-CH (fixed), 
it-IT (fixed), ja-JP (fixed), ko-KR (fixed), ms-MY (fixed), nb-NO (fixed),
nl-BE (fixed), nl-NL (fixed), pl-PL (fixed), pt-BR (fixed), pt-PT (fixed),
ro-RO (fixed), ru-RU (fixed), sk-SK (fixed), sv-SE (fixed), th-TH (fixed),
tr-TR (fixed), uk-UA (fixed), vi-VN (fixed), wuu-CN (fixed), yue-CN (fixed), 
zh-CN (fixed), zh-HK (fixed), zh-TW (fixed)]
```

Comment: I use import Speech in app  no SFSpeechRecognizer !!!!

Comment: @fatemeh You can't have a `SFSpeechRecognizer` without importing the `Speech` library.

Comment: @ Carpsen oooh yes 
For Persian language, I may only use the Google API, and for my other language IOS API